# How to color 3D histogram matplotlib plot like heatmap color

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib, colors

I want to change the colors of my histogram plot to vary by its height as this example:
[image]

My code for histogram plot is

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
nbins = 1000
mean_list = [366, 657, 594, 1200]
scale_list = [15,50,19,7]
height_list = [1200, 300, 900, 600]
n = 0

for z in [30, 15, 10, 0]: 
    ys = np.random.normal(loc=mean_list[n], scale=scale_list[n], size=height_list[n]) # loc is mean

    hist, bins = np.histogram(ys, bins=int(nbins/10))
    xs = (bins[:-1] + bins[1:])/2

    ax.bar(xs, hist, zs=z, zdir='y', alpha=0.8)
    n += 1

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: This does not work with bar plots. Try using `Axes3d.plot_surface`.